# Regex exception for one letter does not fire. JS

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have a simple JS validation in the form of a red line under the input. It just shows where the error is, the main validation takes place on the server.
So, I'm excluding all symbols except those allowed. I also added one language to the exception, which has most of the letters from the English alphabet, with the exception of a few. All of those letters pass validation with the exception of `ə`. It's funny that the lowercase only exception doesn't work for it. At the top, everything works fine.

The code for this letter: `u04D9`.

And here is the function itself:

```
str.replace(/[^\u0400-\u04FF\u00C7\u018F\u011E\u0049\u0130\u00D6\u015E\u00DC\u00E7\u04D9\u011F\u0131\u0069\u00F6\u015F\u00FC\w@.?()+"/,:;*%!№$#=-]+/gu, '');
```

Are there any suggestions how this can be solved?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Your regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/SIv1qg/1) `ə`. Note you do not need `u` modifier, remove it.

Comment: And what could be the problem then? I took the encoding from https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/04d9/index.htm, it should be correct.

Comment: First of all, try without `u`. Next, there are a lot of similarly looking chars like `ə`. Try adding `\u018F\u01DD\u0259\u04D8\u04D9\u1D4A\u2094` to the list of the chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\u04D9` is a `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SCHWA`. The character you have identified is a `LATIN SMALL LETTER SCHWA` with the `\u0259` code. You need to add it to the regex in order to "catch" it.

However, there are [quite a few characters](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C6%8F%C7%9D%C9%99%D3%98%D3%99%E1%B5%8A%E2%82%94) that look similar to chars like `ə`:

```
Ə ‎018F LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SCHWA
ǝ ‎01DD LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E
ə ‎0259 LATIN SMALL LETTER SCHWA
Ә ‎04D8 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SCHWA
ә ‎04D9 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SCHWA
ᵊ ‎1D4A MODIFIER LETTER SMALL SCHWA
ₔ ‎2094 LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER SCHWA
```

It seems reasonable to add `\u018F\u01DD\u0259\u04D8\u04D9\u1D4A\u2094` to the list of the chars.